# channel_post and edited_channel_post response from telegram api

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

my Bot Recently get **chennel_post** message type from telegram api.

this message type sended by a telegram channel?

please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your bot can now get updates about posts in channels. Added new fields channel_post and edited_channel_post to Update.

Ref: [Changelog](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#november-21-2016)